# Restoring elements style using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have the following css:

```
.cls {}
.cls ul {list-style-type:none;}
.cls ul li
{
    border-color:#ff0000;
    border-style:solid;
    float:left;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 2px;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-bottom-width:0px;
    border-top-width:0px;
    border-right-width:0px;
}
```

I assign the class "cls" to a <div> as follows:

```
<div class="cls">
<ul>
<li id="foo">Foo</li>
<li id="bar">Bar</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

If I manipulate element properties using jquery, say I change the border-left-color on the "bar" listitem as follows:

```
$("#bar").css("border-left-color", "#0000ff");
```

Is there a "jquery way" to RESTORE the properties that the listitem "bar" had inherited when the containing <div> was initially assigned the class "cls"?
Obviously without having to do:

```
$("#bar").css("border-left-color", "#ffff00"); }.
```

Something in the form of, $().restoreClass() or equivalent???

Comment: Most of the comments here seem to indicate that $().removeAttr('[style]'); should do the job. I somehow cant seem to make it work, and before I make any conclusion, I just want to be sure the problem is not the jquery version am running

Comment: see my solution.Updated it. I think it can solve your issue.

Comment: please check my solution. Demo included

Comment: UPDATE:

I have to mention here that the suggestion given by @Jose Rui Santos is a pragmatic approach and ideal. 
But when that approach does not render readily, you can use the following to restore the inherited style:

`$('#bar').css({ 'border-left-color': '' });`
 
Somehow, the empty quote restores the previous inherited style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a new class

```
.blueBorder {
 border-left-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Then you can toggle the style with

```
$("#bar").toggleClass('blueBorder'); // with blue border
$("#bar").toggleClass('blueBorder'); // without blue border
$("#bar").toggleClass('blueBorder'); // with blue border
```

This is the best way to toggle style. Keep in mind that you can apply more than one class to a single HTML element, so that you can combine styles together. For example

```
$("#bar").toggleClass('blueBorder');    // with blue border
$("#bar").toggleClass('redBackground'); // with blue border and red background
$("#bar").toggleClass('blueBorder');    // with red background
```

You should keep your presentation (css) separated from the behavior (js), so the following is not recommended:

```
$("#bar").css("border-left-color", "#0000ff");
```

Imagine the work you will have, if you write this a thousand times and later your customer decides to change it to yellow.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/eCXT4/3/)

Comment: Good practice dictates that I should use this approach. However, there are other scenarios where this solution might not be easily adoptable. Like when you dont control the CSS. But food for thought, I wonder why I cant restore by say

    $("#bar").css("border-left-color", "inherit");

or something similar.

Comment: You need to remove the `border-color:#ff0000;` from `.cls ul li`, for the `$("#bar").css("border-left-color", "inherit");` to work. I think the reason for that, is that internally jQuery applies style in "layers of importance", and a `li` style has a higher priority over css classes.

Comment: A less pragmatic approach is to use the following to restore the inherited style: `$('#bar').css({ 'border-left-color': '' });` And thanks @Jose and others.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#bar").css("border-left-color", "");
```

Comment: This does not just remove the style. It restores the inherited one. I would say it partially answer the question since it at least restores one style

Answer (score 1):

When you use .css it adds a style attribute to the element. As long as there was not a style attribute when the page was rendered, calling `$().removeAttr('style')` should do what you want.

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eCXT4/)

Comment: In this case the "bar" listitem had a style from the class "cls"

Answer (score 1):

Try:  `$("#bar").removeAttr('style')`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the particular CSS property and store it in a string.
Then you can restore it when you are done with the change.
But you have to be careful with the name of CSS property :
Here it is working:
http://jsfiddle.net/KgEjr/4/

```
var myOriginal = "" ;

$('#st').click(
    function() { storeAndChange(); } );


$('#re').click(
    function() { restore(); } );


function storeAndChange()
{
    myOriginal = $("#bar").css("border-left-color");

    $("#bar").css("border-left-color", "#0000ff");
    $("#msg").text("changed");
}


function restore()

{

    $("#bar").css("border-left-color", myOriginal);
    $("#msg").text("restored");


}
```

Comment: The example I gave is the simple version. Thats the reason I use the word "say". In the real scenario, I will have modified a number of styles along the way. Worst case scenarios, I can store ALL the original values like you suggest and restore them later. I wanted to see if there is an "easier" way.

Answer (score 0):

Could you store the style in a data attribute and recover it later? This seems to work with your example.

```
$(function(){
    $(".cls ul li").each(function(){
        $(this).data("defaultStyle",$(this).attr("style") || "");
    });

    $("#foo").css({"border-left-color": "#ff00ff", "font-style": "italic", "background-color": "#efefef"});
    $("#bar").css({"border-left-color": "#0000ff", "font-weight": "bold", "background-color": "#cdcdcd"});

    $(".cls ul li").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("style", $(this).data("defaultStyle")); 
    });
});
```